# C Preprocessor compare

Tags: c-preprocessor

I am trying to #define a variable which will determine the value of many other variables throughout my code.

in main.h:

```
#define TOUCHSCREEN     2
#define S1 1
#define S2 2
#define S3 3
```

in conf_usb.h

```
//! Device definition (mandatory)
#if TOUCHSCREEN == S1
#define  USB_DEVICE_VENDOR_ID             0x0914 //
#define  USB_DEVICE_PRODUCT_ID            0x0999 //
#elif TOUCHSCREEN == S2
#define  USB_DEVICE_VENDOR_ID             0x0888 //
#define  USB_DEVICE_PRODUCT_ID            0x1000 //
#elif TOUCHSCREEN == S3 
#define  USB_DEVICE_VENDOR_ID           0x2965 //
#define  USB_DEVICE_PRODUCT_ID          0x5023  //
#endif
```

in lastheader.h

```
#if USB_DEVICE_VENDOR_ID == 0
#   error USB_DEVICE_VENDOR_ID cannot be equal to 0
#endif

#if USB_DEVICE_PRODUCT_ID == 0
#   error USB_DEVICE_PRODUCT_ID cannot be equal to 0
#endif
```

When I have TOUCHSCREEN as S2, the vendor and product id end up being for S1.

If I remove the variable TOUCHSCREEN and just #define S1, S2, & S3, the last header file will throw an error saying the IDs cannot be equal to 0.

Am I comparing wrong? defining wrong? Any and all help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: How exactly are you defining S1, S2 & S3?

Comment: It is in the first section of code posted above.  
//#define TOUCHSCREEN S1
#define TOUCHSCREEN S2
//#define TOUCHSCREEN S3

Comment: That's not what I meant. Here you're defining TOUCHSCREEN=X, but where are you defining S1=Y? This 'Y' is not clear in your question, and is fundamental to understand your problem. The 'X' was already understood.

Comment: If you're not defining S1/S2/S3 anywhere (i.e. you don't have a "#define S1 1", for instance) and the compiler isn't complaining about an undefined symbol, then they are defined somewhere else (could be in a header for a library you're using) and you need to know if they all have distinct values, otherwise you may have the behavior you're reporting. For instance, if S1 and S2 have the same value.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean.  I have defined a value to TOUCHSCREEN, S1, S2 & S3.  After testing the new code, I still am get the same results of getting a product ID for S1 when TOUCHSCREEN should match S2.
::EDIT::

Comment: I checked #if 1==2 #elif 2==2 and it works as expected. product id is correct.  When I check #if touchscreen == 1 #elif touchscreen == 2, #elif touchscreen == S3,  it goes to S3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112093/discussion-between-fabio-ceconello-and-matt).

Comment: Please make a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case I propose to make and post a simple code file demo.c, which includes your headers. I would be interested in inclusion order. That is relevant because main.h needs to be visible (better explicitly included) in all headers which use e.g. S1, S2... Also, I recommend to define TOUCHSCREEN after S1... (this just for readbility) and based on Sn. I.e. `#define TOUCHSCREEN S2`. Do you know that two undefined are usually represented as value 0? Two undefined values are therefor always `==`. And a `DefinedNonZero != UndefinedValue`.